# How do i add a title on top of a thumbnail?

Tags: html, css

It's not my proudest moment to say that I am struggling with this since yesterday, I managed to make my gallery thumbnails look almost like the model in the picture that I uploaded, but I can't add the  "image title" section. I managed at some point to put a title and the gray background, but when I hovered on it, only the image moved and not the title. Please help me so I can get rid of this problem once and forever (Thank you for your time):

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(230px, 1fr));
      gap: 20px;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .box > img {
        width: 80%;
        display: block;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        border-radius: 12%;
    }

    .container img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.04);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>daa</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>Image</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>rrrr</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>strike</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
        <span>strike</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>strike</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>strike</span>
    </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="placeholder-image.png">
        <span>strike</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>strike</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="placeholder-image.png">
      <span>strike</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: Photo of the look I need]

Comment: So what exactly do you want? For the "Image title" text to move on hover with the image? Or just for the image title to be centered in the container with the image and move with it?

Comment: for the image title to be centered in the container at the bottom and to be basically one with the thumbnail and move together with it on hover, not just be like.. on top. I hope i said this right..

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! Thanks for the clarification. I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the hover styling to apply to the title text and the image, just use `transform` on the `.box` container hover state instead of only the image with `.container img:hover`. This way both the `<img>` and the `<span>` text will "move as one" since they are both children of the `.box` parent container. Try this out.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.box .title {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<style>
 .container {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(230px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px;
  
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.box > img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  /* border-radius: 12%;*/
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/17840-200.png" alt="some alt text">
          <div class="title">
            <span>Image Title</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/17840-200.png" alt="some alt text">
          <div class="title">
            <span>Image Title</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/17840-200.png" alt="some alt text">
          <div class="title">
            <span>Image Title</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/17840-200.png" alt="some alt text">
          <div class="title">
            <span>Image Title</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/17840-200.png" alt="some alt text">
          <div class="title">
            <span>Image Title</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```